# How to style a page in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

I'm really new to XAML and Metro and my old HTML skills are not in my advance.

What i want to achive is to have 3 "rows", the top row as some kind of header, the last row as some kind of footer and then a scrollable content area in the middle. 
How can I achive this in XAML for Metro?
I've tried the StackPanel but I can't get the middle one to stop expanding and putting my "footer" out or the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read more about WPF Layouts,
`Grid` in WPF is similar to `Table` in HTML, you should do this if you want `header` and `footer`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/> <!--Header-->
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/> <!--Footer-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Header"></TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <!--your Controls-->
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Footer"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Aaaah! I was really close. I thougt it understood this automatically, but i have to define my elemetens with whick row it's referring to. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Note that Windows Store apps (formerly known as "Metro") do not use WPF. They both are Xaml based, but the details and specific controls are different. 

Safi's Grid example is simple enough to be the same, but for further reading look into the Windows Runtime docs at http://dev.windows.com instead of WPF docs. 

In particular see Quickstart: Defining app layouts at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465337.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<Grid x:Name="GridName">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Header"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Row="1"> 
            <!-- Other Controls -->
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Footer" />
    </Grid>
```